# Can I increase maxBuffer for gruntjs task grunt-svn-export

Tags: gruntjs

The grunt task svn-export runs into an Error:

```
Running "svn_export:dev" (svn_export) task
Exporting from http://path.to/repo
>> #svn export http://path.to/repo target
>> Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded.
```

The task configuration is:

```
svn_export: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      repository: 'http://path.to/repo',
      output: 'target'
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to increase nodejs maxBuffer for a specific gruntjs task?

Comment: Opened a but on github: https://github.com/francisbyrne/grunt-svn-export/issues/1

Comment: Fixed it in a pull request https://github.com/francisbyrne/grunt-svn-export/pull/2 adding an option execOpts